# wxPython wrong file dialog for save file picker?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Consider this example (Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6, python-wxgtk2.8:amd64/trusty 2.8.12.1):

```python
import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx, wx.html
import sys

class Frame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    self.file_picker_inpdffilepath = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", "Open PDF file:", "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf", None, None, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL)
    self.file_picker_outpdffilepath = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", "Choose output PDF file name:", "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf", None, None, wx.FLP_SAVE | wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL | wx.FLP_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    sizer_vmain_app = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_vmain_app.Add(self.file_picker_inpdffilepath, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    sizer_vmain_app.Add(self.file_picker_outpdffilepath, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_vmain_app)
    self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
  app_frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(app_frame)
  app_frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Here I have two file pickers, one should be set up for file load (wx.FLP_LOAD, part of default style), the other for save (wx.FLP_SAVE). When I run this, I get:

[image: wx-filepick.png]

Then I click the "(No..." button, and I get this file open dialog:

[image: load-file-diag.png]

... which is good enough. However, when I click the "Browse" button, which should raise the system dialog for saving files - it raises the exact same one as for the load (regardless of if I use wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL or not)! What I would have expected, is a file dialog that has a text entry widget (so you can select, then rename on the fly), say like this one raised by Firefox's Save Page As...:

[image: Save-As.png]

Is there any way I could force this kind of dialog to show, when clicking on "Browse" of a wx.FLP_SAVE wx.FilePickerCtrl - and if so, how?

Comment: did you try the demo? Also, why not update the wxPython to the latest version?

Comment: Thanks @Igor - how do I try the demo? This is the wxPython version I have on this OS, and I'd like to support it...

Comment: please check the repository - it should contain the list of packages. Somewhere there should be something like wxPython-demo. Also, curious - what happen if you try to run the interpreter and issue "import wx" and then "wx.FileDialog(.....)" where "..." are the parameters you are passing to FilePicker?

Comment: Thanks @Igor, will look up the demo... Also, I tried adding `fdlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Input setting file path", "", "", "CSV files(*.csv)|*.*", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)` as final line in the Frame constructor, and indeed, that dialog is OK... must be a bug in this version of wxWidgets (I checked the code of `wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_controls.py`, the Python code of FilePickerCtrl has nothing to do directly with FileDialog...)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the `FilePickerCtrl` for this. Instead I have always used `wx.FileDialog`. However I just tested your code with wxPython 3.0.2 Classic and it works as expected, so I agree that this is probably a bug in the old version.

If you are stuck with the old version, then you might find the following modified code helpful as it uses `wx.FileDialog` instead:

```
import wx, wx.html
import sys

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.file_picker_inpdffilepath = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", "Open PDF file:", "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf", None, None, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL)
        self.file_picker_outpdffilepath = wx.Button(self, label='Save')
        self.file_picker_outpdffilepath.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSave)
        sizer_vmain_app = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_vmain_app.Add(self.file_picker_inpdffilepath, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_vmain_app.Add(self.file_picker_outpdffilepath, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_vmain_app)
        self.Layout()


    def onSave(self, event):
        path = None
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self,
                      message="Choose output PDF file name:",
                      defaultDir='',
                      wildcard="PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf",
                      style=wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FLP_USE_TEXTCTRL | wx.FLP_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()

        dlg.Destroy()
        return path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    app_frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(app_frame)
    app_frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```